# Is there a function to remove duplicates within a row without removing the entire row using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

```py
import pandas as pd

data=[["John","Alzheimer's","Infection","Alzheimer's"],["Kevin","Pneumonia","Pneumonia","Tuberculosis"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Problem1','Problem2','Problem3'])
```

[image]

In this data frame, I would like to read through each row and remove duplicates so that each person's problem is only reported once. This would mean removing "Alzheimer's" as a duplicate in row 1.
I tried the drop_duplicates() function but this removes the entire row.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your DF in terms of code, preferably with a dictionary constructor (see `df.to_dict()`).

Comment: Done! Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

first to recreate an example of data:

```
import pandas as pd
data=[["John","Alzheimer's","Infection","Alzheimer's"],["Kevin","Pneumonia","Pneumonia","Tuberculosis"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Problem1','Problem2','Problem3'])

df
```

[image]

Now to delete or replace the duplicate with empty space:

```
df['Problem2']=df.apply(lambda x:x["Problem2"] if not(x["Problem2"]==x['Problem1']) else " ",axis=1)


df['Problem3']=df.apply(lambda x:x["Problem3"] if not(x["Problem3"]==x['Problem2'] or x["Problem3"]==x['Problem1']) else " ",axis=1)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! My actual data frame has about 900 columns. Would there be an easier way to do this for all of them?

Comment: @jroy1 - see my answer using apply and duplicated. It will apply to all columns simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `df.duplicated`-function for this. This works similar to `df.drop_duplicates` but returns a boolean series instead of removing the duplicates. You can then index your initial dataframe by this boolean series setting the values to None.

Comment: I provided an example of using `duplicated` in my answer if you want to review it

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` and `duplicated`.

Make sure to use the `axis=1` argument on `apply` to apply to rows instead of columns. `duplicated` will return a boolean series which will set the first occurrence to 'False' by default. Using the opposite of this series with `~` will keep our non-duplicated values and leave out the duplicated ones.

Setup of example

```py
import pandas as pd

data=[["John","Alzheimer's","Infection","Alzheimer's"],["Kevin","Pneumonia","Pneumonia","Tuberculosis"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Problem1','Problem2','Problem3'])

df
    Name     Problem1   Problem2      Problem3
0   John  Alzheimer's  Infection   Alzheimer's
1  Kevin    Pneumonia  Pneumonia  Tuberculosis
```

Deduplication

```py
deduped_df = df.apply(lambda row: row[~row.duplicated()],axis=1)
```

output

```py
>>> deduped_df
    Name     Problem1   Problem2      Problem3
0   John  Alzheimer's  Infection           NaN
1  Kevin    Pneumonia        NaN  Tuberculosis
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a wide-style data frame. I would turn it into long. Thus:

```
data = [["John", "Alzheimer's", "Infection", "Alzheimer's"],
        ["Kevin", "Pneumonia", "Pneumonia", "Tuberculosis"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Problem1', 'Problem2', 'Problem3'])

df.rename(columns=str.lower, inplace=True)  # personal preference
long_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 'problem', i='name', j='index').sort_index()
```

This yields a table that looks like this:

```
                  problem
name  index              
John  1       Alzheimer's
      2         Infection
      3       Alzheimer's
Kevin 1         Pneumonia
      2         Pneumonia
      3      Tuberculosis
```

Then you can just de-duplicate like normal:

```
>>> long_df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(['name', 'problem'])
    name  index       problem
0   John      1   Alzheimer's
1   John      2     Infection
3  Kevin      1     Pneumonia
5  Kevin      3  Tuberculosis
```

If it's a real problem and you *really* need it in wide format, you can just `df.unstack()` then rename the problem-index multi-index to turn it back into a wide data frame with the same form as you used to have.